# How to use JSON API data with button and string values

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-studio

I am currently working on project that returns paragraphs of holy Quran text from json api url.

**JSON Api url "http://quran-endpoint.herokuapp.com/quran/18"**

**And this is my json set text request**

```
String mquran = response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("ayahs").getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(no)).getJSONObject("text").get("ar").toString();
```

Here the "no" is the int that gives sequel number of a paragraph. I want 1 paragraph per page. For this I made this way that with a button click we can change the value int "no" and set text to xml.
every time the button is clicked I want the value "no" to be change to +1 and set it to text and return the paragragh

**or if you have another logic to execute this please help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you can use retrofit as your HTTP client
https://square.github.io/retrofit

with Retrofit you can easily map api responses with data classes
Ex :

```
public class User implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("firstName")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("lastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;

getters/setters ..}
```

then,
create model class for paragraph and put all paragraph into List and then access the List iteratively

```
List<Paragraph>
```

Comment: But how the button will work and change the value of "no" and help in the request queue?